# vb.net: DataBinding of a UserControl-CheckBox and a Class-Property is not updated on PropertyChange

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, user-controls

I made a small UserControl with a checkbox in it and tried to DataBind it to a boolean property of a class. The *DataSourceUpdateMode* of the Binding is set to *OnPropertyChanged*. Unfortunately it doesnt work as desired.

If I change my classproperty, the checkbox reacts immediately BUT not the other way around. Klicking on the Checkbox DOES NOT change the classproperty immediately.  The classproperty only gets updated when you leave the usercontrol (p.e. entering another control). I guess its because the checkbox only gets validated after leaving. But why?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Regards

Christian

Here is some simple code (not c&p, the debugger doesnt give my any errors on the real code):

**The class:**

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class _testClass

    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
    End Sub

    Private _Status As Boolean
    Public Property Status() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Status
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _Status = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Status")
            Debug.WriteLine("CLASS " & value)
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

**The UserControl:**

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class _testcontrol

    Public Event Valuechanged As EventHandler

    Public Property OnOff() As Boolean
        Get
            Return CheckBox1.Checked
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            CheckBox1.Checked = value
            Debug.WriteLine("PROPERTY " & value)
        End Set
    End Property


    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        RaiseEvent Valuechanged(sender, e)
        Debug.WriteLine("EVENT")
        OnOff = CheckBox1.Checked
    End Sub
End Class
```

**The DataBinding:**

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim testclass As New _testClass

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Testcontrol.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("OnOff", Me.testclass, "Status", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple:

DataBinding with OnPropertyChanged only works if the Property and its Event share the same name!

-> Renaming the usercontrol event to OnOffChanged and everything works fine!

Regards cl10k

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your bindings in XAML it is easier and better for the use of wpf. Also using the `CheckBox1.CheckedChanged` event is not databinding. You either databind or hook up the events by hand but databinding is better.

here an example for a `DependencyProperty`:

```
    Public Shared ReadOnly OnOffProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("OnOff", GetType(Boolean), GetType(_testcontrol), New PropertyMetadata("", New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf On_OnOffChanged)))

    Private Shared Sub On_OnOffChanged)(d As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        'Do what you want to do with the new value eg: set OnOff
    End Sub
```

But in your case I'd propably try to bind to the Checkbox directly in wpf and not use a `UserControl` at all.

Edit:

I'm sorry I thought I set the Question-Filter on WPF and didn't see this was a WinForms question ;-)  Unforutnately I don't know anything about the pecularities of WinForm Bindings, so I can't help you. Clearly you shouldn't change to WPF if you've got such a big WinForms Project. For me as a non WinForm-Guy the described behavior makes some sense. If you make a `UserControl` you give the responsibility to handle things to this control. When you leave this control the next layer knows to update. The other direction is Event-Driven so it reacts on change.

But as I said I don't know WinForms.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your answer! 

I dont want to use xaml or wpf. The application I'm working on is completely Winforms and already consists of 30.000 LOC - I can't introduce that many changes at this stage of development...

I forgot to add, that Binding directly to the checkbox within the UserControl via:


`Me.Testcontrol.CheckBox1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Checked", Me.testclass, "Status", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))`


works just fine. Also Binding to a normal Checkbox (without a UserControl) works like desired.